# Hot dryer cord after use

Tags: receptacle, dryer, usa

This question is a follow-up to [this question titled "Dryer door switch"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/236844/dryer-door-switch?noredirect=1#comment457117_236844) which I asked a bit ago.

Thank you to @SiHa who answered my question! I just was using my dryer (which now works). It is a Malber dryer (attached is a picture of the label on the back). It uses a 3 prong outlet, and I am located in the United States. I noticed after using it that the cord was rather warm, and the prongs on the plug were quite hot. Might this be connected to the door switch? Is it something to be concerned about? [image]

Just some more details: I do not recall this happening before. Also, the dryer was on for longer than necessary to dry the things inside.

Comment: So hot that you can't hold and have to let go, or just warm?

Comment: How does the plug feel when plugging in?  Does it feel solid and tight or on the loose side?  If it feels loose then  outlet might be worn out and needs replacement.

Comment: Faulty receptacle, or to be more precise loose connection on receptacle that is arc faulting.

Comment: @JPhi1618 too hot to touch.

Comment: @crip659 it feels solid

Answer (score 3):

There is a little resistance between the plug and receptacle. The surfaces must be clean ( fairly free of oxidation) , and as commented, fit together tightly. Simply pushing the plug in and out a few times should rub it clean, alternately clean the prongs a little with sand paper. You may be able to spring the prongs some, so that they are a tighter fit. As commented, all screw connections must be tight. It is heating according to I squared times R. I is current and the dryer uses a lot, there is nothing you can do about that. You are working on R = resistance. Tight, clean connections to minimize R ; there will always be a little R so it will be warm even when in good shape. As, commented , a new tight fitting , clean plug is an option.